# Get-ADUser -filter paramter quirk

Tags: powershell, filter

I'm taking rows from a HR CSV feed and need to obtain a distiguished name to set a 'manager' property.

The line of code in question is this:-

```
$lineManagerDN = $(get-aduser -filter {CN -eq $row.'line manager'}).distinguishedname
```

....throws an error:-

```
> get-aduser : Invalid type 'System.Management.Automation.PSCustomObject'.
Parameter name: cn
At s:\processCascadeChanges.ps1:51 char:28
+ ... ManagerDN = $(get-aduser -filter {CN -eq $row.'line manager'}).distin ...
```

However, this:-

```
$lineManager = $row.'line manager'
$lineManagerDN = $(get-aduser -filter {CN -eq $lineManager}).distinguishedname
```

...is fine!  Does anyone know why the filter fails on one but not the other?

Many thanks....

Comment: Pretty sure because, `-Filter` is reading the *FilterComponents* as 4 separate tokens getting confused on what you're trying to do. So: `-Filter {CN -eq "$($row.'line manager')"}` should work. Better yet: `-Filter "CN -eq '$($row.'line manager')'"`

Comment: Thanks heaps - your latter suggestion works fine :)

Comment: You could also use `-LDAPFilter "(CN=$($row.'line manager'))"` as an alternative just because I love LDAP syntax hehe